# How to detect when smartwatch is disconnected/unregistered with Smart Extension APIs

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am currently playing with Sony Smart Extension APIs. I need to know when specific device (smartwatch) is registered and unregistered with the smartphone. Registration part is pretty clear, but is there a way to detect when device is unregistered/disconnected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ACCESSORY_CONNECTION_INTENT](http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/aef/registration/Registration.Intents#ACCESSORY_CONNECTION_INTENT)

> Intent sent from the host applications to extensions to indicate that
>   an accessory has been connected or disconnected

Comment: Yes, the above intent is correct, also check the Javadoc API references below for more info on intents. http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/packages

Comment: it will detect when "The accessory is disconnected from the host application".. but it will not trigger when u turn off your watch or watch will not in the range of bluetooth connection.

Comment: @geet - are you saying that there isn't any way for an extension to find out that the watch was turned off or went out of Bluetooth range?